# How About MCQs, True/False, and Fill-In-The-Blank Questions in Undergrad-Level Topology, Analysis, And Abstract Algebra Exams?

Tags: exams

Is it advisable to set questions of multiple-choice, true/false, and fill-in-the-blanks in the bachelor's exam papers of courses on  topology, analysis, functional analysis, and abstract algebra?

Is this practice in vogue at any reputed universities in the USA, UK, Canada, Australia, or anywhere else in the world's more advanced countries?

Can somebody please send me some relevant links to the webpages of some top-ranked universities where past exam papers of these math courses are available?

In which situations are these types of questions preferred over the longer-solution 'subjective type" questions?

Comment: I've not seen more than confirming knowledge of definitions or known facts with multiple- choice or true/false questions. Usually at this stage, you are also looking for proof technique and so ask for simple proofs (prove that this subgroup is normal, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I am not from a top ranked department, but I usually have a few T/F questions just to check understanding of basic definitions and theorems.  I do require a brief justification.  Some examples from a test I gave today "If the linear dipphantine equation ax+by=c has a solution, then gcd(a,b)=c", "If a|c and b|c then (a+b)|c", and "0 divides 0".